# undefined variable in mysqli but it is defined in the constructor

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to use mysqli and it has been giving me an error even though I have been
trying to fix it for hours.

this is the database class

```
class db {

    public $mysqli;

    function __construct(){
        $mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'password', 'database');
    }

    function clean($string){
        $string = $mysqli->real_escape_string($string);
    }

}
```

and when I try to call it in a test page like so,

```
$db = new db();
$db->clean("hi");
```

I get an error:

Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\eat\class\db.class.php on line 12

Fatal error: Call to a member function real_escape_string() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\eat\class\db.class.php on line 12

is there something that I did wrong here? I have been scouring the php manual for a long time and on stackoverflow but it really seems like nobody else is facing this error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php oop variable scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323242/php-oop-variable-scope)

Comment: yea i get what you mean. I had overlooked that point there and it was solved by the 2 gentlement helping me. But somehow, real_escape_string gives a fatal error that I cannot seem to overcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the variable `$mysqli` in the method scope.  You should use `$this` to access object scope.

```
class db {

    public $mysqli;

    function __construct(){
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'password', 'database');
    }

    function clean($string){
        return $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($string);
    }

}
```

Comment: but it would still return 
Fatal error: Call to a member function real_escape_string() on a non-object

Comment: i have no idea why too. IF I were to declare it all in 1 page instead of putting it in a class, it gives me no problems at all.

Comment: You are probably not establishing the connection.  add this after your `new mysqli()` line -- `if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}`

Comment: still the same error. I guess it means that I am connected to the database. Or it would seem so or there would be a new error.

Answer (score 0):

Havent you ever heard of not declaring a variable `As is` inside a class method?

You have to always use `$this->` when refering to variable scope.

Below, is a blue print of how variables are accessed

```
class foo {

$who= "MyName";

function __construct() {

$this->who;

}

}
```

In the above example the `who` inside your functions referes to the variable.

Comment: i have heard of that. that is my bad. but the problem would be with fatal error. Fatal error: Call to a member function real_escape_string() on a non-object

Comment: @NuttyNur I think the problem with that, is you are not passing the mysql connection details in your classes.

Comment: i did pass it through. I did a connection test and it was fine.

Comment: im using mysqli. but going on mysqli_real_escape_string() gives me the same error

Comment: [this](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/199692/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-query-on-a-non-object) help you perhaps

Comment: nope. I tried to apply the same principles they offered seeing as they are about the same error but it does not work because his issue was with his connection not being passed into the method. Mine is passed on and just for the fun of it, I made my connection global to try but it didn't work.

Comment: btw, you should declar global from inside your class. Try it.

Comment: i tried but this problem just wont seem to solve itself. Well, I can see how problematic this is becoming. =(